# 'GridSearchCV' object has no attribute 'best_params_' when using LogisticRegression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, gridsearchcv

Below is the code that I am trying to execute

```
# Train a logistic regression model, report the coefficients and model performance 
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn import metrics

clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)
params = {'penalty':['l1','l2'],'dual':[True,False],'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'fit_intercept':[True,False],
        'solver':['saga']}
gridlog = GridSearchCV(clf, params, cv=5, n_jobs=2, scoring='roc_auc')

cv_scores = cross_val_score(gridlog, X_train, y_train)

#find best parameters
print('Logistic Regression parameters: ',gridlog.best_params_) # throws error
```

The last code line above is where the error is being thrown from. I have used this exact same code to run other models. Any idea why I may be facing this issue?

Comment: irrelevant to the error itself (see answer below for this), we don't use `cross_val_score` for GridSearchCV objects; instead, we use the `best_score_` attribute after fitting the object

Answer (score 2):

You need to fit `gridlog` first. `cross_val_score` will not do this, it returns the scores & nothing else.
Hence, as `gridlog` isn't trained, it throws error.

Below code works perfectly fine:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
diabetes = datasets.load_breast_cancer()
x = diabetes.data[:150]
y = diabetes.target[:150]
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(x, y)
params = {'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
gridlog = GridSearchCV(clf, params, cv=2, n_jobs=2, 
scoring='roc_auc')
gridlog.fit(x,y) # <- missing in your code
cv_scores = cross_val_score(gridlog, x, y)
print(cv_scores)
#find best parameters
print('Logistic Regression parameters: ',gridlog.best_params_)
# result:
Logistic regression parameters: {'C': 1}
```

Comment: You may want to update the answer to point out that we normally don't use `cross_val_score` for GridSearchCV objects; instead, we use the `best_score_` attribute after fitting the object

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be updated such that the LogisticRegression classifier is passed to the GridSearch (not its fit):

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer # For example only
X_train, y_train = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

params = {'penalty':['l1', 'l2'],'dual':[True, False],'C':[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 'fit_intercept':[True, False],
        'solver':['saga']}

gridlog = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), params, cv=5, n_jobs=2, scoring='roc_auc')
gridlog.fit(X_train, y_train)

#find best parameters
print('Logistic Regression parameters: ', gridlog.best_params_) # Now it displays all the parameters selected by the grid search
```

**Results**

```
Logistic Regression parameters:  {'C': 0.1, 'dual': False, 'fit_intercept': True, 'penalty': 'l2', 'solver': 'saga'}
```

Note, as @desertnaut pointed out, you don't use `cross_val_score` for GridSearchCV.

See a complete example of how to use GridSearch [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-grid-search-digits-py).
The example use a SVC classifier instead of a LogisticRegression, but the approach is the same.